Horror/Rom-com where woman cooks husband's heart into meatloaf?
I remember seeing this movie in a hotel a couple years ago, but for the life of me cannot remember the name or any of the actors. I believe the actors were American, although I could be wrong:
What is remembered from the plot:

It has a cheery, romcom-like tone, revolving around a woman who's known for her meatloafs and has a dream about going to France. 
Eventually, her husband(boyfriend?) confronts her, saying that he is involved with another woman, and that he thinks her dream to go to France is ridiculous. 
She stabs him with a knife, cooks his heart into a meatloaf, and then leaves it on the other woman's doorstep with a French flag on the top. 
It shows the woman eating it later- the movie still has the cheery tone, rather than horror.
The movie then shows the main woman in France, eating at a bakery/cafe often because she falls in love with the man working there, and he invites her to a park, where it turns out he's hanging out with his wife and children.

Other than that, I do not remember much about the film, and have been desperately trying to find out what it was.

EDIT: There may have been a narrator, but I am not 100% sure. The park where the woman met with the French man and his family had a bridge and a pond.

The Cook, the Thief, His Wife & Her Lover from Peter Greenway

English gangster Albert Spica has taken over the high-class Le Hollandais Restaurant, run by French chef Richard Boarst. Spica makes nightly appearances at the restaurant with his retinue of thugs. His oafish behavior causes frequent confrontations with the staff and his own customers, whose patronage he loses, but whose money he seems not to miss.
Forced to accompany Spica is his reluctant, well-bred wife, Georgina, who soon catches the eye of a quiet regular at the restaurant, bookshop owner Michael. Under her husband's nose, Georgina carries on an affair with Michael with the help of the restaurant staff. Ultimately Spica learns of the affair, forcing Georgina to hide out at Michael's book depository. Boarst sends food to Georgina through his young employee Pup, a boy soprano who sings while working. Spica tortures the boy before finding the bookstore's location written in a book the boy is carrying. Spica's men storm Michael's bookshop while Georgina is visiting the boy in hospital. They torture Michael to death by force-feeding him pages from his books. Georgina discovers his body when she returns.
Overcome with rage and grief, she begs Boarst to cook Michael's body, and he eventually complies. Together with all the people that Spica wronged throughout the film, Georgina confronts her husband finally at the restaurant and forces him at gunpoint to eat a mouthful of Michael's cooked body. Spica obeys, gagging. Georgina then shoots him in the head, calling him a cannibal.

